# Some clarification about how Spring MVC use the @RequestMapping annotation to implement RESTfull architecture

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, annotations

I am studying for the Spring Core certification and I have some doubt about how Spring MVC handle REST web service.

Reading the documentation I found this example:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/orders", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public void listOrders(Model model) {
    // find all Orders and add them to the model
}

@RequestMapping(value="/orders", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public void createOrder(HttpServletRequest request, Model model) {
    // process the order data from the request
}
```

Ok, it show 2 Spring MVC method (that I think should be declared into a controller class, is it true).

These methods both handle HTTP request towards the **/orders** resource (according to the REST style in which a **resource** is seen as a programming element that manages a kind of data and a state and provide processing on this kind).

In this case if the HTTP request toward the **/orders** is a **GET** it will be executed the **listOrders()** method that return the list of all objects but if the request toward the **/orders** is a **POST** it will perform the **createOrder()** that create a new order

So what exactly means, that using the **method** paramether of the **@RequestMapping** annotation I can handle the HttpRequest according to the RESTful style?

Comment: see also Spring Data REST project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

REST is an architecture style that uses the various HTTP methods to model actions on resources.

Spring's `@RequestMapping` annotation is just a way to map a handler method to an HTTP request. The `method` attribute simply restricts which HTTP methods can be handled by the annotated method.

Comment: Ok, this is clear for me. But is it thinked to bundle together a resource with a specific HTTP method (the so called "verbs")?

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: In a RESTful web api that use HTTP protocol I have to use the HTTP method set (GET, PUT, POST, DELETE) on a specific resource. So my question is: it it the  method=RequestMethod.XXX the proper way used by Spring MVC to handle the HTTP method (the verbs) to a resource specified by the @RequestMapping annotation?